# Problem updating an Entity

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a problem when updating an entity (User) in my application.

The entity is located in session when the user has been logged. So I made it:

```
Dim u as User = (From x in ctx.Users).First()
Session("user") = u
```

Ok, no problem yet.

But when I need to change the user:

```
Dim u as User = Ctype(Session("User"),User)
u.name = "new name"
ctx.Users.ApplyCurrentValues(u)
```

I got the follow error:

> An object with a key that matches the
>   key of the supplied object could not
>   be found in the ObjectStateManager.
>   Verify that the key values of the
>   supplied object match the key values
>   of the object to which changes must be
>   applied.

Comment: What is the primary key of u set to after the first line of each code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First example cannot work until you do this:

```
Dim u as User = Ctype(Session("User"),User)
u.name = "new name"
(From x in ctx.Users).First()
ctx.Users.ApplyCurrentValues(u)
ctx.SaveChanges
```

ApplyCurrentValues only take values from passed object and copies them to the same object type which must be loaded and attached to the context.

Second example shown by @Mlantosca cannot work because you are storing entity in session and you didn't detach it. To make it work you must use:

```
Dim u as User = (From x in ctx.Users).First()
ctx.Detach(u)
Session("user") = u
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this:

```
ctx.Users.Attach(User);
ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(User, EntityState.Modified);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

this is the style I use when I update existing entities in EF

-Michael

Comment: didn't work =/ An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker